# Apache no connection because target machine refused it

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I have an apache server on my local network. however, I am getting the error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.1.*.

I have also tried using wget localhost on my server and even that is getting the error the target machine has actively refused the connection.

I have stopped shorewall, ufw, denyhosts and ossec services and still no luck. Any ideas on anything else to try?

Could it be my ISP has port 80 blocked?

Comment: can you pl clarify : 1) If the machine is on your local network, where does your ISP comes in picture ? 2) the respective IPs of the server and client ?

Comment: 192.168.1.8 is server...192.168.1.5 is client

Comment: try a telnet to 192.168.1.8 80 . If it succeeds that will mean port 80 is open on 192.168.1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if you have something like

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from  192.168.16.100
    Allow from 192.168.16.0/24
</Location>
```

Deny from all is not needed. In fact it will screw up because everything will match all, and thus denied (and I think Apache is trying to be smart and do something stupid). I have always found Apache's Order, Allow and Deny directives confusing, so always visualize things in a table (taken from the docs):

```
Match      | Allow,Deny result   | Deny,Allow result
-------------------------------------------------------
Allow only | Allowed             | Allowed
Deny only  | Denied              | Denied
No match   | Default: Denied     | Default: Allowed
Match both | Final match: Denied | Final match: Allowed
```

With the above settings:

Requests from 192.168.16.100 get "Match both" and thus denied.
Requests from 192.168.16.12 get "Allow only" and thus allowed.
Requests from 123.123.123.123 get "No match" and thus denied.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...It had to do with zend-server. I uninstalled it and re-enabled php5 and apache2 and it was working.